# How to set text to go over an image strictly in HTML?

Tags: html

I am writing an emailed newsletter, and need to set an image as the footer, with a few clickable links over it. I have figured it out using both HTML and CSS, but no matter where I searched I could not find a way to do this strictly using HTML. Can anyone help me out?

```
<!--Footer-->
                        <tr id="footer">
                        <td id="footer" style="font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;background-image: url" img url"" templates\uuaemail-foot.jpg";padding-left:="" 20px;padding-right:="" 20px;padding-top:="" 10px;padding-bottom:="" 20px;"="">
                        <table height="101" width="602">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td id="footer" style="font-size: 10px;color:white;" height="95" valign="top" width="600" align="center"><p><br></p><p class="style3"><strong><span style="font-size: 12px;">admissions.rutgers.edu<br></span></strong></p><p class="style3"><span class="style7"><span style="font-size: 8px;"><strong> University Undergraduate Admissions</strong>, Operations Center<br>©2017 , an equal opportunity, affirmative action institution.</span></span></p></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
```

Is what I currently have (with CSS styling)

update: My issue is that the email is widely sent to Ms Outlook 2016, which I have both heard and seen through testing that it does not process CSS styles very well. When I opened this code in Outlook, it showed the CSS styling commands at the top of the message, and did not apply it at all.

Comment: You can add the css code in html with the style tag, but without css you cant achieve things like this. Even a <h1> </h1> tag adds css code automaticly.

Comment: Can you add the html code please.

Comment: edit image and put text as an image part then use the new edited image... it is only the way

Comment: Rakesh Soni - if he adds the link texts as a part of the image, the whole image can only be linked to single target, not individual links, that might break the functionality.

Comment: are you type your code correctly? its full of errors in `background-image` and `:=` strings in `padding-left:="" 20px;padding-right:="" 20px;padding-top:="" 10px;padding-bottom:="" 20px;"=""`

Answer (score 0):

CSS is just an organized way for the the stylesheet. Although not recommended, you can use inline styles with just the HTML to achieve almost everything, if you post your code, may be some of us can suggest a definite answer.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is a markup language, it does neither add functonality or style by itself.

There are tags there **the browser** places default values.

Eg.

```
<footer> </footer>
```

The most browser add automaticly:

```
footer { 
    display: block;
}
```

Or the h tag

```
<h1></h1>
```

The most browser set the default values like:

```
h1 { 
    display: block;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-top: 0.67em;
    margin-bottom: 0.67em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Every other style change has to be done by your self with css. You can also work with inline stlyes like:

```
<h1 style="color:red;"> A red big text </h1>
```

A good way to find more about default values and inline styles is: https://www.w3schools.com/

Answer (score 0):

You want to use background image in your email and you want it rendered in outlook. Use this site http://backgrounds.cm/ to generate code for background image that will work in all outlook desktop versions. Then you can add links etc. over the image.

Also, please don't use same id more than once in your code. You can assign an ID to one element only. To cover multiple elements, use class attribute.